# kNN classification using scikit-learn: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, typeerror, knn

I am trying to predict the name of attribute `area` which has `object` as its `dtype` using `longitude` and `latitude` having `float` as their `dtype`. I am using kNN algorithm but I am getting this error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'`

I am confused about the data types in the use of kNN. Could I get any help with understanding what I am doing wrong here? Here's my code:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier, KNeighborsRegressor

# read csv file

df = pd.read_csv("perfectData.csv")
X = np.array(df.ix[:, 13:])
y = np.array(df['area'])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=90)
y_train=y_train.ravel()
y_test=y_test.ravel()

knn = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=3)

# fitting the model
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)

# predict the response
pred = knn.predict(X_test)

print(pred)
```

Comment: Are there column names in your file? Pandas will assume the first row has the the columns headers.By the sounds of it `area` seems to have the issue, if long and lat have `float dtype`. Check the `area` column for strings

Comment: And this error is thrown on which line? Please include the stack trace along with some data samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to remove `ravel()`:

```
df = pd.read_csv("perfectData.csv")
X = np.array(df.ix[:, 13:])
y = np.array(df['area'])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

knn=KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)
knn.fit(X_train,y_train)
prediction=knn.predict(X_test)
```